# Swift - play sounds parallel with spotify

Tags: ios, swift, api, avaudioplayer, spotify

Is it possible to play a sound in swift when another one is being played, my client wants to make an app that emit sounds while spotify is playing songs too, is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant have multiple apps playing sounds at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so that means that even notifications can't be played ?